python: Unclosed client session warning when downloading blob from ADL Gen 2 async
I have an Azure function app that reads blobs and then process them. I'm getting this warning Unclosed client session
Main calls the getblob function using await
import logging
from ..shared import blobOpsAIO
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
from ..shared import invOps
import sys, os

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        file_name_path = req_body.get("file_name_path", "")
        file_name = req_body.get("file_name", "")
        account_id = req_body.get("account_id", "")

        inv = await getBlob(file_name_path, file_name, container_name=account_id)

        #process inv


Downloading the file
getblob:
async def getBlob(blobPathName, LOCALFILENAME, dtype_param = None, container_name = 'somevalue', blob_type = 'csv', encoding='UTF-8', skiprows=0, header=0, sep=','):

        df = pd.DataFrame()
        # some validations   
        df = await read_blob_content(connection_string, container_name, blobPathName, blob_type, LOCALFILENAME, dtype_param, encoding, skiprows, header, sep)
        # do something with df
        return df

async def read_blob_content(connection_string, container_name, blob_name, blob_type, LOCALFILENAME, dtype_param, encoding, skiprows=0, header=0, sep=","):

                async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                    blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(
                        conn_str=connection_string,
                        container_name=container_name,
                        blob_name=blob_name
                    )
                    print(f'Going to fetch blobPathName: {blob_name}')
                    blob_data = await blob_client.download_blob()
                    async with aiofiles.open(LOCALFILENAME, "wb") as my_blob:
                        data = await blob_data.readall()
                        await my_blob.write(data)
                    await session.close()    # also tried placing this line one level up in the identation 
                success = True
            

            #open the file using pandas and process
                
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        raise e

I have tried to adding/removing the await session.close() with no success. Also placing the line at the same identation level than the async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session

I am able to get the expected result without any warning message using the below code.
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
import aiohttp
import aiofiles
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

connection_string='*********';

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
async def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        file_name_path = req_body.get('file_name_path')
        file_name = req_body.get('file_name')
        account_id = req_body.get('account_id')

        inv = await get_blob(file_name_path, file_name, container_name=account_id)

        # Process inv
        return func.HttpResponse(f"File {file_name} downloaded and processed successfully!", status_code=200)
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
        return func.HttpResponse("An error occurred while processing the request.", status_code=500)

async def get_blob(file_name_path, file_name, dtype_param=None, container_name='test', blob_type='csv', encoding='UTF-8', skiprows=0, header=0, sep=','):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    try:
        df = await read_blob_content(
            connection_string,
            container_name, file_name, blob_type, file_name_path, dtype_param, encoding, skiprows, header, sep
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
        raise e
    
    # Process the dataframe
    return df

async def read_blob_content(connection_string, container_name, blob_name,blob_type, file_name_path, dtype_param, encoding, skiprows=0, header=0, sep=","):
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(
                conn_str=connection_string,
                container_name=container_name,
                blob_name=blob_name
            )
            logging.info(f'Going to fetch blobPathName: {blob_name}')
            blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
            async with aiofiles.open(file_name_path, mode='wb') as my_blob:
                data = blob_data.readall()
                await my_blob.write(data)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
        raise e
    
    # Read the file using pandas and process
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name_path, dtype=dtype_param, encoding=encoding, skiprows=skiprows, header=header, sep=sep)
    
    return df

requirements.txt
azure-functions
pandas
aiohttp
aiofiles
azure-storage-blob


Blob is downloaded locally.



